# How to Model Ordinal and Categorical Data to conduct regression analysis?

Tags: r

I'm struggling on how to model my data in order to predict the frequency of social contact according to different categories of urban areas in R. First of all, I might say I am new into Data Sciences, so please if you find that any term is wrongly described, please let me know.

So in my case, the data I have is the following:

Social contact Frequency is defined by Never(1), Rarely(2), Monthly (3), More than once a Week (4), Weekly (5), Daily (6). The categories of urban configuration are: Pure residential (1), Mixed (2), Mostly Commercial (3), Purely Commercial (4).

I tried to handle the social contact frequency data as count data by transforming it on count data and then conducted a generalized linear model with poisson regression. The problem I encountered is overdispersion.

Now, I wonder if there is another way of conducting analysis with these two kinds of data that might be more accurate than converting ordinal into count data.

I would be very thankful to hear your recommendations, literature or other advices.
Kind regards,
Victoria

Comment: I think a very good explanation is in the following answer:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73065/correlation-coefficient-between-a-non-dichotomous-nominal-variable-and-a-numer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poisson regression requires that you have a nonnegative integer response as the count of events per observation. It is apparently not appropriate to your data. For example, those choosing "Rarely" and "More than once a Week" may have very different frequencies between, sometimes as many times as, each other. What you have is an ordinal response instead of count data. Accordingly, you should use an ordinal regression. See a basic example by UCLA https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/ and my answers on ordinal regression [Is there a method in R that allows me to change my outcome variable to a factor after multiple imputation with mice, and then pool ordinal regression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334549/)